# Fixing windows MBR without Vista Recovery CD

Tags: windows-vista, mbr

I had Windows Vista + Ubuntu running on my system. I deleted the ubuntu partitions from Windows. However, when I start the system, GRUB throws up an Error 22 (missing partition) and does not let me boot into Windows.

The CD ROM on my laptop is fried and therefore I tried installing Ubuntu again using a USB install. However, the version Ubuntu 9.10 justs hangs in the load screen and does nothing. I do not have windows Vista Recovery CD (as it was a recovery partition in my laptop).

What are the options I have? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have also found using [Trinity Rescue Kit](http://trinityhome.org/) and the test disk application that comes with it great in this type of situation. test disk is ran from the command line, but not to difficult to understand just make sure to read everything before making choices, but it can fix your MBR, partion tables, boot sectors, etc.

Comment: i tried this, and didn't see any explicit "vista" or "mbr" options, but this did seem like a useful cd.... i found another boot cd that does have mbr options, and would boot my "hidden" vista partition straight up (mbr tools in "Dos Programs") section... http://www.hirensbootcd.org/

Comment: as a follow up, i found a boot cd that definitely had the option to restore the Vista MBR, and is derived from hirensbootcd, but has way more in it too.... See this post on SU for more info: http://superuser.com/a/467161/38941

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Universal USB Installer: http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/
2. Create an Ubuntu LIVE USB - [GOLDEN WORD - LIVE]
3. Boot from the USB and shoot up gparted, play with the partition, the rest is easy.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download a copy of the windows vista recovery cd, burn it and recover your MBR with bootrec.exe

1. Get a torrent client
2. Get your disk from [here](http://neosmart.net/blog/2008/windows-vista-recovery-disc-download/).

   - There are disks for x86, ia64 and windows 7
3. Burn it
4. Boot from the Recovery CD (it's also a vista installation disk)
5. Choose keyboard Layout and press *Next*
6. Press 'Repair Computer'
7. Press 'Command Prompt'
8. Execute `bootrec /mbr`

   - more info on bootrec.exe in Microsoft's kb.

Voilá

Comment: Anti spam prevented me to add link to microsoft knowledge base article   

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us2

Comment: I did this to recover a laptop mbr. It was from a vendor who gave me disc to recover it to a factory default state but no to fix mbr.